# Using Fourier Series to acquire Nonlinear ODE Periodic Solutions

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, series-expansion, fourier-analysis, nonlinear

For the following Cauchy problem of a non linear ODE:
\begin{equation}
\ddot{x}=-|x|^{1/3}
\end{equation}
which satisfies the initial conditions $x(0)=1, \dot{x}(0)=0$, I am aware that there are periodic solutions, since it is a conservative system.

To simplify further, it is acceptable to start without the absolute value and solve the corresponding system:
\begin{equation}
\ddot{x}=-x^{1/3}
\end{equation}
for the same ICs. 
I would like therefore to expand this $x(t)$ into Fourier series and acquire an approximation of these periodic solutions.

So far I am aware that *Mathematica* has a built in function for taking the Fourier series of a function but what I want actually to do is the following:

> By considering that:
>   \begin{equation}
> x(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{2n-1} \cos ((2n-1)\omega t)
> \end{equation}
>   and plunging it into the ODE I get the following:
>    \begin{equation}
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{2n-1}\cos \left( (2n-1)\omega t \right)=\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\beta A_{2n-1}\cos \left( (2n-1)\omega t \right) \right]^3
> \end{equation}
>   where $\omega$ the frequency and $\beta=\left( (2n-1)\omega \right)^2 \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Now I would like to expand and acquire the coefficients $A_n$.

I am not sure whether this piece of code exists already or if I should try to write it, but for the latter one I do not believe it would be an easy task to do since my coding skills unfortunately are limited.

How can I tell *Mathematica* to expand and equate the coefficients $A_n$ so that it gives me back their expression? And if there is not a general one *(which is highly improbable since I have proved that these orbits exist for these particular ICs)* how can I acquire at least the first say m $A_1, \cdots, A_m$, where $m<n$?

Comment: Note that \beta depends on `n`.

Comment: True. I will correct it, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Direct solution of the last equation in the question also is feasible, because the Fourier series converges very rapidly. as will be seen below.  The equation for a three term expansion can be written as

```
Sum[a[n] (n w)^6 Cos[n w t], {n, 1, 5, 2}]^3] - Sum[a[n] Cos[n w t], {n, 1, 5, 2}] == 0
```

Reducing the cubic terms in terms of `Cos[m w t]` shows that the equation contains terms as high as `Cos[15 w t]` (as would be expected).

```
Collect[TrigReduce[Sum[a[n] (n w)^6 Cos[n w t], {n, 1, 5, 2}]^3] - 
    Sum[a[n] Cos[n w t], {n, 1, 5, 2}], _Cos, Simplify];
```

Consistent with the left side of the original equation, only terms up to `Cos[5 w t]` should be retained.  Extract their coefficients and equate them to zero to provide three simultaneous equations determining the three `a`.

```
Thread[Coefficient[%, Cos[# w t] & /@ Range[1, 5, 2]] == 0]
(* {1/4 (3 w^18 a[1]^3 + 2187 w^18 a[1]^2 a[3] + 24911296875 w^18 a[3]^2 a[5] + 
    2 a[1] (-2 + 3 w^18 (531441 a[3]^2 + 11390625 a[3] a[5] + 244140625 a[5]^2))) == 0, 
    -a[3] + 1/4 w^18 (a[1]^3 + 68343750 a[1] a[3] a[5] + a[1]^2 (4374 a[3] + 46875 a[5]) + 
    2187 (531441 a[3]^3 + 488281250 a[3] a[5]^2)) == 0, 
    -a[5] + 3/4 w^18 (531441 a[1] a[3]^2 + a[1]^2 (729 a[3] + 31250 a[5]) + 
    15625 (1062882 a[3]^2 a[5] + 244140625 a[5]^3)) == 0} *)
```

Solutions for the three `a` then are obtained (slowly) by.

```
sol = Simplify[Solve[%, {a[1], a[3], a[5]}, Reals], 
    w > 0 && a[1] != 0 && a[3] != 0 && a[5] != 0];
```

Although most of the seven solutions are truly enormous in `LeafCount`, insight can be gained from sample numerical evaluations.

```
sol /. w -> 1.
(* {{a[1] -> 0, a[3] -> 0., a[5] -> 0.}, 
    {a[1] -> 0, a[3] -> 0., a[5] -> -5.91207*10^-7}, 
    {a[1] -> 0, a[3] -> 0., a[5] -> 5.91207*10^-7}, 
    {a[1] -> 0, a[3] -> -0.0000586649, a[5] -> 0.}, 
    {a[1] -> 0, a[3] -> 0.0000586649, a[5] -> 0.}, 
    {a[1] -> -1.23839, a[3] -> 0.000315137, a[5] -> -5.77387*10^-6}, 
    {a[1] -> 1.23839, a[3] -> -0.000315137, a[5] -> 5.77387*10^-6}} *)
```

The first result is trivial, and the next four results correspond to solutions for, in effect, harmonics of `w == 1`.  Only the last two solutions are of interest, and one is the negative of the other.  So, we can restrict attention to `Last@sol`.  Although the values of `a` vary rapidly with `w` (shown here for `a[1]`),

```
ListLogPlot[(a[1] /. Last[sol] /. w -> #) & /@ Range[.001, 10.002, .5], 
    DataRange -> {0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {w, a[1]}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

the ratios `{a[[2]]/a[[1]], a[[3]]/a[[1]]}` are essentially constant at `{-0.000254473, 4.6624*10^-6}` except for `w < 0.01`.  Thus, `a[1] Cos[w t]` typically is a very good approximate solution to the ODE.  This assertion can be further substantiated by comparing the single-cosine approximation with the solution from the earlier symbolic solution.

```
GraphicsRow[Show[
    ParametricPlot[{{qp - Sqrt[fp[[1]]], x}, {qp + Sqrt[fp[[1]]], -x}, 
        {3 qp - Sqrt[fp[[1]]], -x}, {3 qp + Sqrt[fp[[1]]], x}} /. c -> #, 
        {x, 0, 100}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotPoints -> 500], 
    Plot[(2 c/3)^(3/4) Cos[t Pi/(2 qp)] /. c -> #, {t, 0, 4 qp /. c -> #}, 
        PlotStyle -> Dashed]] & /@ {1/100, 1, 100}, 
    ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Agreement is excellent for `c` in the range of `1/100` to `100`.

Comment: Amazing job. What's more you have been explaining the whole way what you are doing, thank you. I have a question, why the plot of the solution from your previous answer regarding the symbolic solution does not coincide with the ones at the end of your Fourier analysis?

Comment: Also, I get an error about the "qp" parameter in your last Parametric plot:/

Comment: @Mitscaype  Actually, the plots are the same, if account is taken of the periodicity of the solution.  You encountered the `qp` error, because I neglected to define `qp`.  Now, I have done so.  See the end of the earlier answer for its definition.

Comment: @Ahh, I see. Therefore, if changing the period to $\omega=5.30304$ which corresponds to the solution of $x(0)=1, \dot{x}(0)=0$ will give me the correct results, since you showed and I verified that the ratio $A_3/A_1, A_5/A_1$ is a constant. Moreover, on your previous reply, $C[1]$ is $x(0)$, right?

Comment: @Mitscaype  The amplitude of the oscillatory solution is given by `(2/3)^(3/4) c^(3/4)`, not by `c`.  See the second to the last equation in my earlier answer.

Comment: Hello and sorry for my late answer I was away. But the amplitude as written above, it does include $c$. That $c$ is defined by the ICs of the system, is that correct? Excuse my questions, they may sound simple but I am trying to figure out the code in order to use it properly. Thank you!

Comment: @Mitscaype  The dashed curves in the final set of three plots are given by `(2 c/3)^(3/4) Cos[t Pi/(2 qp)] `, so the amplitude is `(2 c/3)^(3/4)` and the period is `4 qp`.

Comment: It seems that I am missing something and I am not able to figure it out. In the first answer of yours, there is an analytical solution to the ODE given by Mathematica. In order to plot this, we need a set of ICs. You write that we can set $C[2]=0$ without loss of generality and then select $C[1]=c\to 2$ in order to plot the solution is that correct? Therefore we chose a set of ICs. Also amplitude does indeed depend on $(2/3)^(3/4)c^(3/4)$ and not only $c$, but it is different for each choice of $c$. My initial ICs were $x(0)=1, \dot{x}(0)=0$. Do they apply here? I am confused with $C[1],C[2]$

Comment: I did not consider your initial conditions, because `DSolve` often works better without ICs.  In any case, they would correspond to `c == 3/2` and the time shifted by `qp` computed with that value of `c`..

Comment: How did you figure out that they would correspond to that value of $c$? I am asking, just to understand how am I able to manipulate your code in order to use my own set of ICs. :)

Comment: @Mitscaype  From my earlier answer, the maximum value of the solution is given by x == (2/3)^(3/4) c^(3/4) .  In your question, you specify the maximum value of `x` to be `1`.  Solving the equation I just gave in this comment yields `c == 3/2`.

Comment: Alright, I think I have managed to figure out everything :) Thank you for having the patience to go through this with me!

Comment: I made a correction to the main body of the question, where $\beta$ was to the power of $6$ now it is correctly written as $\beta=\left( (2n-1)\omega \right)^2$. This changes the numerical results a bit, but the behavior remains the same.

Comment: Is it possible to solve the system of equations in the same way?

Comment: @dtn  To what system of equations are you referring?

Comment: @bbgodfrey - https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224544/approximate-solution-of-a-nonlinear-ode-in-the-form-of-a-fourier-series-containi

Comment: I need help with this question.

Answer (score 7):

This problem can be solved symbolically as follows.  First, note that the first integral of the first ODE is given for `x[t] > 0` by

```
x'[t]^2 + x[t]^(4/3)/(2/3) == c
```

where `c` is a constant of integration.  Proof:

```
Simplify[D[x'[t]^2 + x[t]^(4/3)/(2/3) - c, t]/(2 x'[t])]
(* x[t]^(1/3) + x''[t] *)
```

Similarly, for `x[t] < 0` the first integral is

```
x'[t]^2 + (-x[t])^(4/3)/(2/3) == c
```

The resulting phase-space plot for `c == Range[2, 40, 2]` is

```
Show[ContourPlot[xp^2 + x^(4/3)/(2/3), {x, -5, 5}, {xp, -5, 5}, 
         Contours -> Range[2, 40, 2], ContourShading -> None], 
     ContourPlot[xp^2 + (-x)^(4/3)/(2/3), {x, -5, 5}, {xp, -5, 5}, 
         Contours -> Range[2, 40, 2], ContourShading -> None], 
     FrameLabel -> {x, x'}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

To obtain the actual symbolic solution for `x[t] > 0`, use

```
DSolve[x''[t] + x[t]^(1/3) == 0, x, t]
(* Solve[(1/(2 C[1] - 3 x[t]^(4/3))) Sqrt[6] C[1]^(3/2) 
   (EllipticE[I ArcSinh[(3/2)^(1/4) Sqrt[-(1/Sqrt[C[1]])] x[t]^(1/3)], -1] - 
    EllipticF[I ArcSinh[(3/2)^(1/4) Sqrt[-(1/Sqrt[C[1]])] x[t]^(1/3)], -1])^2 
   (4 - (6 x[t]^(4/3))/C[1]) == (t + C[2])^2, x[t]] *)
```

If Mathematica could `Solve` this expression, it would have.  So, extract and `Simplify` the unsolved equation.

```
f = Simplify[%[[1]] /. {C[1] -> c, C[2] -> 0, x[t] -> x}, c > 0]
(* 2 Sqrt[6] Sqrt[c] (EllipticE[ArcSin[((3/2)^(1/4) x^(1/3))/c^(1/4)], -1] - 
                      EllipticF[ArcSin[((3/2)^(1/4) x^(1/3))/c^(1/4)], -1])^2 == t^2 *)
```

The corresponding solution for `x[t] < 0` is obtained by replacing `x` by `-x`.  Note that `C[2]` is the initial value of `t` and has be set to zero without loss of generality.  The plot of these expressions for `c -> 2` (corresponding to the innermost curve in the plot above) is

```
ParametricPlot[{{Sqrt[f[[1]] /. c -> 2], x}, {-Sqrt[f[[1]] /. c -> 2], x}, 
                {Sqrt[f[[1]] /. c -> 2], -x}, {-Sqrt[f[[1]] /. c -> 2], -x}}, 
    {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Black, AxesLabel -> {t, x}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

The turning point is given by

```
Solve[First@Cases[f[[1]], ArcSin[z_] -> z, Infinity, 1] == 1, x][[1, 1]] 
(* x -> (2/3)^(3/4) c^(3/4) *)
```

and the quarter period of the solution by

```
qp = Sqrt[f[[1]] /. %]
(* 2^(3/4) 3^(1/4) c^(1/4) (EllipticE[-1] - EllipticK[-1]) *)
```

For `c -> 2`, the turning point and full period (`4 qp`) are `1.24081` and `6.30736`, consistent with the second plot.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide an answer. Nevertheless, I have some questions. At the part where you use {DSolve} you have some Elliptic functions involved. How did this come up? Also, the way I understand it, is that you did not took at all the Fourier approximation of $x(t)$, but you found period in a different way, is that correct?

Comment: @Mitscaype  The Elliptic functions are part of the solution obtained by `DSolve`.  They are not uncommon in ODEs that can be reduced to first integrals of the motion.  I found the period by computing the point at which `x'[t]` vanished.  Given the results in my answer, it would not be difficult to obtain the corresponding Fourier coefficients, but I felt that you would not need them, given the complete answer.  I can provide answers to other questions, if any, tomorrow.  It is late here now.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, the fact that you could compute a period means that there are indeed periodic solutions to the problem, right? I really would like the procedure to acquire the Fourier $A_n$ along with $\omega$ and then plot this solution to the one acquired by DSolve. Again, many thanks for your time and help. Anytime tomorrow is fine :)

Comment: @Mitscaype  The solutions provided in my answer all are periodic, and all periods (or frequencies) are allowed.  Because the equation is nonlinear, the waveform depends on the frequency.  I shall look at the Fourier amplitudes question later today.

Comment: Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Interestingly enough, Mathematica gives an error of maximum stepsize when I tried to solve the ODE, for the same ICs with NDSolve. Why would this happen? The solution does exist in an implicit form so I am guessing some problem with the domain of $x(t)$?

Comment: @Mitscaype  I cannot answer your question with certainty without seeing your code. With respect to your earlier question, the frequency and first three coefficients of the Fourier solution corresponding to c -> 2 above are `{w -> 0.996162, a[1] -> 1.282,a[3] -> -0.000326235, a[5] -> 5.9772*10^-6 }`.  This very fast convergence is consistent with numerical comparisons I also have made.  I shall add these results to the answer in an hour or so.

Comment: Hello and excuse this late comment of mine. I was going through the steps again, since I would like to implement what we did here to another problem and I noticed that as you say the turning point is given by: `Solve[First@Cases[f[[1]], ArcSin[z_] -> z, Infinity, 1] == 1, x][[1, 1]] `. Can you please explain why `f[[1]]`, after you solved it for `ArcSin[z_]==z`, has to be equal to `1` for it to be a turning point? I am actually not familiar with elliptic integrals and since the problem was about Fourier I did not think I would need it. But thats the beauty of it in math, isn't it? :)

Comment: @Mitscaype  `Cases[f[[1]], ArcSin[z_] -> z, Infinity, 1]` extracts the argument of  `ArcSin` from the left side of `f`.  That argument must lie between `-1` and `1` for the `ArcSin` to have a real value.  Thus turning points occur when the argument of `ArcSin` has one of those two values.  I chose `1` for convenience.

Comment: I see, now it seems more reasonable. And then you connect the turning point with the quarter period of the solution. Is that a formula? I found some stuff in wiki about the quarter period elliptic function but it does not mention the turning point as a perquisite to find `qp`. Again, thanks for taking the time to explain.

Comment: @Mitscaype  Look at the second figure, and you will realize why the distance from the origin to the turning point is a quarter period.

Comment: Alright, then I was thinking exactly the same thing. Therefore, it is more of a geometric derivation of `qp` and I totally can understand it. Thank you.