# Approximate solution of a nonlinear ODE in the form of a Fourier series containing the coefficients of the initial ODE

Tags: differential-equations, dynamic, nonlinear

In this topic we considering nonlinear ODE:

$\frac{dx}{dt}= (x^4) \cdot a_1 \cdot sin(\omega_1 \cdot t)-a_1 \cdot sin(\omega_1 \cdot t + \frac{\pi}{2})$ - Chini ODE

https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=odeadvisor%2FChini

And system of nonlinears ODE:

$\frac{dx}{dt}= (x^4+y^4) \cdot a_1 \cdot sin(\omega_1 \cdot t)-a_1 \cdot sin(\omega_1 \cdot t + \frac{\pi}{2})$

$\frac{dy}{dt}= (x^4+y^4) \cdot a_2 \cdot sin(\omega_2 \cdot t)-a_2 \cdot sin(\omega_2 \cdot t + \frac{\pi}{2})$

Chini ODE's NDSolve in Mathematica:

```
pars = {a1 = 0.25, ω1 = 1}
sol1 = NDSolve[{x'[t] == (x[t]^4) a1 Sin[ω1 t] - a1 Cos[ω1 t], x[0] == 1}, {x}, {t, 0, 200}]
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sol1], {t, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

System of Chini ODE's NDSolve in Mathematica:

```
pars = {a1 = 0.25, ω1 = 3, a2 = 0.2, ω2 = 4}
sol2 = NDSolve[{x'[t] == (x[t]^4 + y[t]^4) a1 Sin[ω1 t] - a1 Cos[ω1 t], y'[t] == (x[t]^4 + y[t]^4) a2 Sin[ω2 t] - a2 Cos[ω2 t], x[0] == 1, y[0] == -1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 250}]
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol2], {t, 0, 250}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

There is no exact solution to these equations, therefore, the task is to obtain an approximate solution.

Using `AsymptoticDSolveValue` was ineffective, because the solution is not expanded anywhere except point `0`.

The numerical solution contains a strong periodic component; moreover, it is necessary to evaluate the oscillation parameters. Earlier, we solved this problem with some users as numerically:
[Estimation of parameters of limit cycles for systems of high-order differential equations (n> = 3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222656/estimation-of-parameters-of-limit-cycles-for-systems-of-high-order-differential)

*How to approximate the solution of the equation by the Fourier series so that it contains the parameters of the original differential equation in symbolic form, namely $a_1$, $\omega_1$, $a_2$  and $\omega_2$.*

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Consider providing "Chini ODE" reference in  your question.

Comment: Interesting problem.  I whish I had time now to try to solve it.  By the way, `x[0] == 0` gives a more obviously periodic solution to the first ODE, and that is what an FFT analysis is likely to yield.

Comment: This is not urgent, but the sooner the better (I think in two or three days we can try to figure it out). I am also working on this, and so far without success.

Comment: Over what range of `a1` are you interested?  The numerical solution becomes singular at about 2,374, requiring an infinite number of trig functions to represent.

Comment: Range $a1$ and $a2$ = [0.001..0.5]

Comment: For large $a$, the system becomes unstable. It would be nice, by the way, to track this moment.

Comment: I was writing the answer when you made your last comments, so I could not reply immediately.  I hope that you find it useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution addresses the first nonlinear ODE.  The second system, two coupled nonlinear ODEs, can be treated in a similar way.  To begin, rescale `t` and `a1` to eliminate `ω1`, simply as good practice.  Here are solutions for four values of `a1`, the first three obtained using code of the form:

```
With[{a1 = 0.1}, NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == (x[t]^4) a1 Sin[t] - a1 Cos[t], 
    x[0] == x[2 Pi]}, x[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]];
p1 = Plot[%, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, AxesLabel -> {t, x}, 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}, PlotLabel -> "a1 = 1/10"]
```

However, experimentation shows that the maximum value of `a1` for which periodic solutions exist is just above `a1 = 2.374`.  For `a1` near that value, instead use:

```
With[{a1 = 2.374}, FixedPoint[NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == (x[t]^4) a1 Sin[t] - a1 Cos[t], 
    x[0] == #}, x[2 Pi], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, MaxStepSize -> 0.00001] &, -20., 
    SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-5 &)]]
With[{a1 = 2.374}, NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == (x[t]^4) a1 Sin[t] - a1 Cos[t], x[0] == %}, 
    x[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, MaxStepSize -> 0.00001]];
p4 = Plot[%, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {t, x}, 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}, PlotLabel -> "a1 = 2.374"]

GraphicsGrid[{{p1, p2}, {p3, p4}}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Evidently, for values up to about `a1 = 1`, the solution is approximately sinusoidal, but much less so for larger values.

To obtain symbolic expressions for a Fourier expansion of the solution of the ODE, as requested in the question, begin by assuming that `x[t] == 0` in the right side of ODE, solve it to obtain a first approximation to the solution, insert it into the right side of the ODE, solve again, and iterate to obtain power series in `a1`:

```
Clear[a1];
Nest[Collect[DSolveValue[{x'[t] == a TrigReduce[Sin[t] #^4] - a Cos[t]}, x[t], t] 
    /. C[1] -> 0, {_Sin, _Cos}, Simplify] &, 0, 4];
sa = Collect[Expand[%] /. (a^n_ /; n > 13) :> 0, {_Sin, _Cos}, Simplify]
(* (-((5 a^5)/8) + (6067 a^13)/7680) Cos[t] + ((5 a^5)/48 - 
   (1070681 a^13)/3225600) Cos[3 t] + (-(a^5/80) + (2118019 a^13)/16128000) Cos[5 t]
   - (62353 a^13 Cos[7 t])/2257920 + (5917 a^13 Cos[9 t])/1612800 - 
   (9277 a^13 Cos[11 t])/35481600 + (67 a^13 Cos[13 t])/5990400 + 
   (-a + (63 a^9)/160) Sin[t] - 17/80 a^9 Sin[3 t] + (67 a^9 Sin[5 t])/1200 - 
   (37 a^9 Sin[7 t])/6720 + (a^9 Sin[9 t])/2880 *)
```

Applying this expression to `a1 = .75` yields a curve indistinguishable to the eye from that obtained numerically.  Of course, for larger values of `a1` (but still less than `1`) more Fourier terms and larger powers of `a1` are needed.

Fourier series can be obtained for  `a1 > 1` but not as symbolic functions of `a1`, by using the approach illustrated in [my answer to 145760](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145929/1063).  For instance,

```
a1 = 2; m = 11;
f[t_] := Sum[c[n] Cos[n t] + s[n] Sin[n t], {n, 1, m, 2}]
TrigReduce[f'[t] - (f[t]^4) a1 Sin[t] + a1 Cos[t]];
eq = Join[Thread[Simplify[Coefficient[%, Cos[# t]] & /@ Range[1, m, 2]] == 0], 
    Thread[Coefficient[%, Sin[# t] & /@ Range[1, m, 2]] == 0]];
sf = f[t] /. FindRoot[eq, Join[Array[{s[#], .1} &, (m + 1)/2, {1, m}], 
    Array[{c[#], .1} &, (m + 1)/2, {1, m}]]] 
(* -1.09709 Cos[t] - 0.293228 Cos[3 t] - 0.0992651 Cos[5 t] - 
   0.0448225 Cos[7 t] - 0.0219299 Cos[9 t] - 0.0115066 Cos[11 t] - 
   0.762219 Sin[t] - 0.0697846 Sin[3 t] - 0.0430293 Sin[5 t] - 
   0.0328824 Sin[7 t] - 0.0205152 Sin[9 t] - 0.0134693 Sin[11 t] *)
```

Plotting this expression yields a curve indistinguishable from that computed numerically above.  In  principle, it might be possible to solve the equations just above without inserting a numerical value for `a1`, but doing so would require symbolically solving twelve coupled polynomial equations, each of 12th order.  In practice, doing so would be very time-consuming.

Comment: @dtn  Thank you for accepting my answer.  What action have you taken on the two-ODE case?

Comment: @dtn  Also, you might find `pars = {ω1 = 3, a1 = 0.25 ω1, ω2 = 4, a2 = 0.2 ω2};
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == (x[t]^4 + y[t]^4) a1 Sin[ω1 t] - a1 Cos[ω1 t], y'[t] == (x[t]^4 + y[t]^4) a2 Sin[ω2 t] - a2 Cos[ω2 t], x[0] == x[2 Pi], y[0] == y[2 Pi]}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]` as a slightly better sample problem

Comment: Have you tried to solve this problem using the symmetries of Lie groups?

Comment: Maybe this equation can be analyzed using vector fields, Pfaff equations, etc. It's just that I'm trying to find an even more effective way.

Comment: @dtn  I have not tried to solve the second problem using Lie group symmetries.  What symmetries do you think exist?  I am not familiar with the theory of Pfaff equations, although I assume that the goal of all the methods you mention is to reduce the dimensionality of the problem.  Doing so certainly would be helpful.

Comment: I have a book, _V.P. Krasnoshenko, A.P. Krishchenko. Nonlinear systems: geometric methods of analysis and synthesis_. There is a paragraph: _Pfaff's equations and a qualitative study of dynamical systems_. If you have the time and interest to study the material, I can send you a page scan. There are few of them. I myself am studying this book now, trying to find something useful. It, of course, is in Russian, but it is not difficult to translate the text. I can help with that.

Comment: @dtn  There was a time when I could read a bit of Russian, but now all I can do is recognize cognates.  That may be sufficient, though, so please do send me copies of the relevant pages, along with a copy of the cover page.  brendan.godfrey@ieee.org     By the way, Lie group symmetries, which you mentioned, usually imply invariants.  Are you aware of any?

Comment: I’ll try to make page scans in the next couple of days. I also noticed the structure of the right side. $(x^4) \cdot a_1 \cdot sin(\omega_1 \cdot t)-a_1 \cdot sin(\omega_1 \cdot t + \frac{\pi}{2})$  Does it look like a “rotation” of a certain vector? And then we can assume that there is a coordinate transformation ...

Comment: About Lie symmetries and groups previously did not know anything at all. Only with in-depth study of the topic did I come across this method.